# How to set time count down in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, time, countdown

I want to set time count down like start with 60sec then elapsed 59,58,57 etc... this elapsed time show in bottom of the screen, How to set this?
Please help me

Thanks in Advance

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Articles/usingTimers.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use like:

Declare a `NSTimer` object on the `@interface` like `NSTimer *aTimer;`

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    aTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(elapsedTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)elapsedTime
{
    static int i = 60;

    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];

    i--;
    if(i<0)
    {
       [aTimer invalidate];
       aTimer = nil;
    }
}
```

Here label is a `IBOutlet UILabel`, that is set to interface.

Comment: @Minu: yes you can ask. I'll help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `NSTimer` see my example -
Declared

```
NSTimer *timer;
int count;
```

Globally in your `ViewController.h` class

Then you can start your count down in `viewDidLoad:` method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //label is your **UILabel**
    label.text = @"60";
    count = 59;
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(countDown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

-(void)countDown
{
    if(count > 0)
    {
        label.text = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:count] stringValue];
        count --;
    }
    else
    {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}
```